# Stop output of a process started in background

Tags: linux, ubuntu-server

I want to start a new process in the background so I entered "ls/usr -R1 &", however I can still see the output. How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dude - what do you *expect*?  More to the point: what exactly do you *want*?  If you want the output to go to a text file, use redirection: `ls/usr -R1 > myfile.txt &`.  If you want to completely separate the process from your logon, use [nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup).  If you want to e-mail the output to yourself, use a pipe: `ls/usr -R1 | /usr/sbin/sendmail -s "My ls -R" test@email.com`.  Etc etc - it all depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Two aspects you have to consider here:

1. take a look at the `nohup` utility and
2. read about "output redirection"

This leads to something like:

```
nohup kwrite 2>&1 &
```

*where `kwrite` obviously is just an example.*

You will find the actual output and error output of the process in the file `nohup.out`. You can monitor that file too. If you don't want any output (careful here!), then you can finally redirect stuff to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward stdout, so in order to do this you use ">".

Do the following:

```
ls/usr -R1 > /dev/null &
```

Cheers